# How to split panda dataframe based on colum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this question is being asked here multiple times, but I could not find a quick answer to my problem. I have the below dataframe. I want to split this dataframe based on two columns values. So I if the col1 value is 1 and column 2 is also has also value 1 split it. So from row 0 to 3 split it and also again from row 6 to 9 split it and put it in a separate dataframe. Is there any code where i can look for it. Thanks in advance. My real dataframe contains 1000+ rows

df

```
  col1    col2    col3
0  1        1      3
1  1        1      6
2  1        1      9
3  1        1     12
4 11        1     13
5  1        0      3
6  1        1      6
7  1        1      9 
8  1        1      6
9  1        1      9
```

Comment: Can you please provide the exact expected output for clarity? Also, please don't undo my edits, the data is easier to copy/paste this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can craft a mask with [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to identify the valid rows and form a group with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to use in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to split:

```
m = df[['col1', 'col2']].ne(1).any(axis=1)

dfs = [g for _,g in df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())]
```

Output:

```
[   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     3
1     1     1     6
2     1     1     9
3     1     1    12,
    col1  col2  col3
6     1     1     6
7     1     1     9
8     1     1     6
9     1     1     9]
```

Intermediates:

```
   col1  col2  col3      m     ~m  m.cumsum()
0     1     1     3  False   True           0
1     1     1     6  False   True           0
2     1     1     9  False   True           0
3     1     1    12  False   True           0
4    11     1    13   True  False           1
5     1     0     3   True  False           2
6     1     1     6  False   True           2
7     1     1     9  False   True           2
8     1     1     6  False   True           2
9     1     1     9  False   True           2
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you very much. Next step is to get only the lists which is longer than ten rows. Thanks againa mozway

Comment: @WilliamAshoti for that use `dfs = [g for _,g in df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum()) if len(g)>10]`

Comment: Hi mozway,  i just want to understand the code. can you explain a little bit? For example this code m = df[['col1', 'col2']].ne(1).any(axis=1) and what happend if I want to change the value of 1 and want 11 instead. What will be the solution then? Thanks in advance

Comment: Then `m = df[['col1', 'col2']].ne(11).any(axis=1)`. Both both columns, if not equal (`ne`) to 11, in `any` of those two assign `True`

Comment: One final question is. If I want to say find first in col1 the value 11 and if you find it take the the values below in col1 and col2 if the values in col1 and col2 are equal to 1. Thanks in advance mate

Comment: Then I guess `m1 = df['col1'].eq(11) ; df[['col1', 'col2']].eq(1).all(axis=1); [g for _,g in df[m1|m2].groupby(m1.cumsum())]` You should try to understand how it works, this is more or less always the same logic.